# Jquery $(this) is not being called

Tags: jquery, attributes, this

I am trying to show a warning message as alert if attribute "clickDisabled" is "disabled". I am unable to pass $(this) value to a function ShowDisableWarning(). How can I do that?

```
 function showDisableWarning(e) {

            if ($(this).attr('clickDisabled') == 'disable') {

            alert($(this).attr("title"));

                return false;
            }
        }

     $(document).on('click', '.btnSubmit', function (e) {
             showDisableWarning(e);
     });

    <div clickDisabled="disable">
    </div>
```

Comment: I think You should use "call()" function to pass "this". I might be wrong but I dont understand how div is connected with the function to be used as "this" inside.

Answer (score 2):

Change to this

```
    function showDisableWarning(e) {

        if ($(this).attr('clickDisabled') == 'disable') {

            alert($(this).attr("title"));

            return false;
        }
    }

 $(document).on('click', '.btnSubmit', showDisableWarning);

<div clickDisabled="disable">
</div>
```